# Umbraco - Refresh node's parent in content tree from action handler

Tags: c#, umbraco

I've seen similar posts on this on the umbraco forum, but none that I have read have addressed my exact problem.

I have an action handler that is called when a node is published.  I would like for the last thing the action handler does be to refresh the content tree, starting at the node's parent.

Assume the following structure:

- Z

  - Za
  - Zi
  - Zu

Suppose I publish the node, "Zi".  I would like for the "Z" folder to refresh (and keep "Zi" selected in the editor).

Is this possible?

The closest I managed to come was using

`umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.Current.ClientTools.SyncTree(doc.Parent.Path, true);`

This did refresh the tree, but it also collapsed all nodes.  I'd like to keep the "Z" node expanded in the example I gave above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the sub-folders (**Za**, **Zi**, **Zu**) open and highlight **Zi**, you shold pass the path of zi rather than the path of **Z**. This will refresh and highlight **Zi** but it will refresh the subtree for **Z** as well.

So-

```
umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.Current.ClientTools.SyncTree(doc.Path, true);
```

If **Z** does not refreshed *enough* then you could call SyncTree for **Z** first, then for **Zi**.

```
umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.Current.ClientTools.SyncTree(doc.Path, true);
umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.Current.ClientTools.SyncTree(doc.Parent.Path, true);
```

---

Ultimately these calls end up as javascript on the page.
In Umbraco 4.7.0 (I haven't tried it on anything newer) the call -

```
UmbClientMgr.mainTree().syncTree('-1,1000,10001', true);SyncTree("-1,1000,1001", true);
```

- ends up as -

```
UmbClientMgr.mainTree().syncTree('-1,1000,1001', true);
```

- in the page's javascript when the page html comes back.

So outputting that javascript directly instead of using UmbClientMgr should allow you to put multiple lines in.

In practice calling for the parent node's path will close the parent node's subtree and refresh the parent node. A subsequent call for the child node will expand the parent subtree to show and highlight the child node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried both of your solutions, as well as a third which was switching the order of the two lines in your 2nd solution.  Calling `SyncTree(doc.Path, true)` just reloads the current node in the context tree.  Calling `SyncTree(doc.Parent.Path, true)` reloads the entire context tree and collapses all nodes.  Neither are what I'm looking for.  What I want is the exact same behavior as if I had right-clicked Z and clicked "Reload Nodes".

Comment: As another idea, you may be able to throw the resulting javascript in there by hand. See my amendment.

Comment: it might be that only one of the javascript calls gets output to the html.

Comment: Mat, thanks a ton!  This is the bit of code that ended up doing the trick - `((BasePage)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "<script>UmbClientMgr.mainTree().syncTree('" + documentObject.Parent.Path + "', true);</script>");`